# Windows Mobile development in Windows 8

Tags: visual-studio-2008, windows-8, windows-8.1, windows-mobile

I'm currently on windows 7 but we've recently bought new hardware and we're "upgrading" to windows 8.1 (and presumably 10 soon) but I'm having compatibility problems.  We need to be able to develop for windows mobile (as opposed to windows phone) but I can't seem to get it working on windows 8.  I managed to get VS 2008 SP1 installed but when I try to install any of the WM SDKs, they complain that VS isn't installed and won't let me proceed.  I'm dreading having to keep my windows 7 machine running just for WM development but this is what I'm facing.

Does anyone know if it's possible to develop for WM on windows 8?  Or conversely, does anyone KNOW that it's not possible?  I haven't been able to find a definitive answer so far.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I had Visual Studio 2008 Standard Edition installed instead of Professional.  Installing Professional fixed the problem.